# Convert or Cast from StringCollection to ObjectCollection?

Tags: vb.net

I would like to populate a listbox with a list of installed printers in VB.net.

This works:

```
Dim printerList As System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.StringCollection
printerList = System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters

For Each printerName In printerList
    ListBox1.Items.Add(printerName)
Next
```

This does not work:

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(printerList)
```

...because of the following type-conversion error:

> Public Sub AddRange (value As
>   System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection)': Value of type
>   'System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.StringCollection' cannot be
>   converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection'.

Is it possible to directly cast one to the other for use in AddRange() as shown? Or is the loop the only (or most efficient) way?

Comment: Does StringCollection support `ToList` or `AsEnumerable`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you're dealing with 2 collections that were created before the more modern generic lists and enumerables, so their use is less fluid.

In this case, the `AddRange` method accepts either another `ObjectCollection` instance (not your case), or an array of `Object`s.  If you want to benefit from the latter, you'll need to transform the `StringCollection` instance to an array of `Object`s. Here is how this can be done:

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(printerList.Cast(Of Object)().ToArray())
```

That said, I would stick with your current `For Each` loop. It is very readable, and doesn't create an intermediate array.  But, I doubt either choice will make much difference, so pick your favorite.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to learn about the process, commands, & syntax as much as actually making it work (assuming it could be done in one line of code at all). And you're correct; the loop is more readable and it does already work.